# alGenSources keeps giving a random source

Tags: c++, objective-c, cocos2d-x, openal, pcm

I was recently given some code by a friend that's meant **to convert then play and analyze music**, but when I have tried integrating it into my own project, it is throwing errors and refusing to play the music.

I've tracked the flow of the code and found the first line where it disagrees from the original.

```
#define AL_CALL(a) { a; checkError(__FILE__, __LINE__); }
bool PcmStream::open(string path){
printf("PcmStream %s", path.c_str());
fp = fopen(path.c_str(), "rb");
if(!fp){
    printf("Audio file at path %s is missing", path.c_str());
    return false;
}
fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_END);
file_size = ftell(fp);
fseek(fp, 0L, SEEK_SET);
printf("File size %lu Bytes", file_size);

AL_CALL(alGenBuffers(BUFFERS_NUMBER, buffers));
AL_CALL(alGenSources(1, &source));
printf("\n \n First error %u \n \n", *buffers);

printf("\n \n Second error %d \n \n", source);
```

This outputs:
**BytesOpenAL error 40964 at /Users/justking14/projectname/template/multi-platform-cpp/proj.ios/PcmStreamer.cpp 61**

First error **2496**

Second error **0**

*buffers always gives the same number on this project and a different, but constant number on the original code.

Source always gives the same number on the original, but on my code it gives anything between 0 and 2089734272.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the shared SimpleAudioEngine I was using was blocking the audio ports.